# Linux make file executable inside service

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I do have service looking like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=API environment service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/api
ExecStart=/var/www/api/api
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=apache
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install]
```

Service works but every time I copy new files to that folder through ftp I need to run `sudo chmod +x /var/www/api/api` to make that file executable and then do `sudo systemctl restart api.service`

My question is is it possible to somehow add line at top of this service which will make this file executable if it is not so i only need to run restart command?

Comment: Your FTP client should already make it executable for you.

Comment: Nope it doesnt. I tried deleting everything, adding files again and restarting service it does not work. Then i make it executable and restart service and it does indeed work

Comment: I can solve only part of your problem - do not run the executable directly, but run a bash script which runs it. Therefore even you need to retype `chmod +x /var/www/api/api` you do not need to restart the service.

Comment: Following @GeorgeY . For example, if `api` binary is `python` replace `ExecStart=/var/www/api/api` by `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/api/api"` so you don't need to have it executable.